# Can you "Change the Look" after changing the master page?

Tags: master-page

I am trying to upload a new color palette for our top branding bar, went to Change the Look under site settings, selected my style & colors. I click Try it out and this comes up. I've altered the master page so can I reapply these after altering it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details? What does the technical detail link provide by way of ULS log errors or otherwise? What changes you made to the look, did you use code? Is this the out of the box master or did you create a new one?

Comment: click on "Technical Details" and grab the correlation ID. From the SharePoint Shell run Merge-SPlogfile -correlation <past id> -path <past to outfilefile>.txt  This will give you relevant information.  Look for exceptions in the details column.  If you paste the results into your question we can also help decipher that.

Comment: are you editing the Master page or HTLM source of master page.

Comment: It won't let me click on the Technical Details or Go Back to Site links so I can't get the correlation id. I think that may be because this is a preview window and I don't want to keep it just in case I can't revert it. I have only modified the ootb master page and not the html source.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. I had modified my master page and each time I did, I would copy the current one, append the date to it and make the copy my active master page just in case I had to roll it back. This did cause the "Change the Look" section to look at my original seattle.master page and not the new one with the date appended.

To fix this, I had to create a preview file that had my new master page name seattle_20150518.preview. Then when I went to change the look, this new preview file appeared in the Site Layout and would let me apply any new changes.